# How to integrate mxgraph into webpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, mxgraph

I am trying to integrate mxgraph library into a webpack / rails project.

However I am facing an issue.

I tried to follow the webpack example in the repo:
https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/webpack/src/anchors.js

However, when I load the page including the container, it raises an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

For this corresponding row:

```
mxGraph.prototype.getAllConnectionConstraints = function(terminal, source)
```

I suppose that this declaration does not work properly:

```
var mxgraph = require("../../../node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/dist/build"),
    mxGraph = mxgraph.mxGraph,
    mxShape = mxgraph.mxShape,
    mxConnectionConstraint = mxgraph.mxConnectionConstraint,
    mxPoint = mxgraph.mxPoint,
    mxPolyline = mxgraph.mxPolyline,
    mxEvent = mxgraph.mxEvent,
    mxRubberband = mxgraph.mxRubberband,
    mxCellState = mxgraph.mxCellState;
```

In brief, what is the right way to include mxgraph into a webpack/rails project?

Thank you in advance!